# Link displaying on the site title

Tags: html, web

Hi guys I have a problem I'm building an email and well for the subject line I'm putting things like this:

```
<title>Hello</title>
```

but on IE 9 its displaying like this on the tab when I hover:

```
Hello
www.placewhereIhost.com/public/index.html
```

and I don't know why is this happening.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Could you please share your source code?  It's really just guesswork for us unless we can try to find the problem.

Comment: Is that your website address thats showing when you hover on the title?

Comment: No is just an example of what is showing imagine there the site url.

Comment: So is it the site url that is showing on title hover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On IE, if you do hover over the tab it'll always show the link.

[image: IE tab]

So, if you go to Google, StackOverflow, etc., they'll all produce the same result, though they don't have a link in the title itself. That's something in IE itself, not your code.

However, if you try a different browser like Chrome, it will not produce the same result.